# Jquery - Changing .jpg to .gif for src as well as srcset

Tags: jquery, replace

So I want to be able to have the responsive images of wordpress (specified in srcset) while switching the .jpg to .gif on hover of a parent row.

I have been able to get this to work for src but not for srcset. I am quite the rookie when it comes to jquery.

```
$j(".featured-row").mouseenter(
    function() {
        var src = $j("img", this).attr("src");
        var srcset = $j("img", this).attr("srcset");
        $j("img", this).attr("src", src.replace(/\.jpg$/i, ".gif"));
        $j("img", this).attr("srcset", srcset.replace(/\.jpg$/i, ".gif"));
    }),
$j(".featured-row").mouseleave(function() {
    var src = $j("img", this).attr("src");
    var srcset = $j("img", this).attr("srcset");
    $j("img", this).attr("src", src.replace(/\.gif$/i, ".jpg"));
    $j("img", this).attr("srcset", srcset.replace(/\.gif$/i, ".jpg"));
});`
```

As I mentioned the part for replacing the src works fine. Just not the srcset.

A sample img url is given below

```
<img width="1060" height="600" src="http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2.jpg" class="vc_single_image-img attachment-full" alt="" srcset="http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2.jpg 1060w, http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2-300x170.jpg 300w, http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2-768x435.jpg 768w, http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2-1024x580.jpg 1024w, http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2-700x396.jpg 700w" sizes="(max-width: 1060px) 100vw, 1060px">
```

Comment: Add the `g` flag to your regexp in the `srcset`, you have more than one replacement to do in the string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The srcset attribute contains:

`srcset="http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2.jpg 1060w, http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2-300x170.jpg 300w, http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2-768x435.jpg 768w, http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2-1024x580.jpg 1024w, http://adwaitpawar.com/niyo/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/n15-2-700x396.jpg 700w"`

These contain mulitple `.jpg` so you should add the global modifier`/g`.

Also, your regex matches `.jpg$` with a dollar sign which would match `.jpg` at the end of the line.

You could update this line:

`srcset.replace(/\.jpg$/i, ".gif")`

to

`srcset.replace(/\.jpg/gi, ".gif")`

And

`srcset.replace(/\.gif$/i, ".jpg")`

to

`srcset.replace(/\.gif/ig, ".jpg")`

Comment: Excellent. This fixes my problem for the most part. Thank you.